# Hadoop on Azure Create New Cluster

Tags: azure, hadoop, azure-hdinsight

I am able to create a new Hadoop cluster through the interface, but need to create a new cluster on request.  Does anyone know if an API exists to create a new cluster?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not yet. As of now (Preview) you must be using Windows Azure Management Portal Interface to create Hadoop cluster in your windows Azure Subscription.

As most of the Windows Azure Management functionalities are available on Powershell, it is possible to have such functionality built into Powershell over REST as described [here](https://github.com/WindowsAzure/azure-sdk-tools/issues?labels=&milestone=11&page=1&state=open) however I don't know any immediate plans.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can.

The Azure CLI allows you to control HDInsight clusters from a batch file for example. You then get a bunch of HDInsight control functions. Type

```
azure hdinsight
```

to see all the built in help. It covers all the basics (listing, creating configuring clusters) and the multiple storage account functionality.

This is I believe based on the nodejs sdk. To get going, install nodejs and

```
npm install azure-cli
```

This should give you what you need to be able to manage the clusters from the command line.

Answer (score 0):

By asking "Create a new Hadoop cluster", I believe you mean Hadoop HDInsight Cluster.

If yes, then we can create a powershell(.ps1) script, which can do  the job for you. 
Here is the sample script which might be useful.

http://mydailyfindingsit.blogspot.in/2016/01/create-script-hdinsight-cluster.html